# sonataadmin - add form field at the begining of the ertain existing tab only if condition is true

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

I have $form and some fields in the different tabs, that works okay, I want to add a field into the form

```
$this->getSubject()->getId()
```

if this condition is not NULL

What I did, after defining form that should be visible in all conditions i added this part of code, to add field url in the tab dimension (tab dimension is already added in previous formmapper definition):

```
if($this->getSubject()->getId()  !== NULL){
$formMapper
        ->with('tab.dimension')
                ->add(
                'url',
                null,
                [
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            )
->end();
}
```

But the error i recive is:

```
New tab was added automatically when you have added field or group. You should close current tab before adding new one OR add tabs before adding groups and fields.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tab like this. If you want to add grouping than use it with function.

```
if($this->getSubject()->getId() !== NULL) {
            $formMapper
                ->tab('dimension')
                    ->add('url', null, [
                        'required' => false,
                    ])
                ->end();
        }
```